# Conversion of .txt into.dat

Tags: c++

I have a txt(ascii) file but i wish to convert this file into binary (dat) file using c++ but i am very new in c++ programming.so I juct opend my 2 files:myBinaryfile and myTxtFile but I don't know how to write those data into new dat file.so i want to write a c+ codes that takes in an input containing ascii(.txt) file, and converts it to binary .dat in an output file and vice verse.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, it's more of a request for someone to write your program for you.  -1

Comment: You have asked three other questions relating to text to binary conversion, what is wrong with the other questions/answers? In particular, waht was wrong with this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016262/need-to-convert-txt-file-into-binary-file-in-c/5021016#5021016) answer?

Comment: i need to write code like above psudo codes. because, i need to know what is happening inside this conversion. i have to randemly access data in my .dat file. so i should know how conversion is taken place line by line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google the following words: `iostream`, `fstream`, `boost.serialization`. Also, consider reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901209/using-iostream-to-serialize-user-objects) question.